# Bootstrap collapse button not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Whenever I click on the collapse button, nothing happens. I have checked it on both of my laptops, so I guess there is no problem with the web browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>QPZONE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">QPZONE</a>

        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">

        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>



        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">1st Year</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">2nd Year</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">3rd Year</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">4th Year</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>


    </nav>           
    <script type="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have the required dependencies installed?  Make sure that you have `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.min.js` in the `js` folder.  Also, do you know how to access the Developer Console by pressing Ctrl+Shift+J or Ctrl+Shift+I to see the error log?  The error log will give you an idea of what is causing the problem. If you don't understand it, copy/paste the error here and we can help you.

Comment: Raunak, were you able to get this solved?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Check Dependencies**

Do you have the required dependencies installed? Make sure that you have `jquery.js` and bootstrap.min.js in the `js` folder, and `bootstrap.min.css` in the `css` folder?

**2. Check the Error Log**

Do you know how to access the Developer Console by pressing Ctrl+Shift+J or Ctrl+Shift+I to see the error log? The error log will give you an idea of what is causing the problem. If you don't understand it, copy/paste the error here and we can help you.

Answer (score -1):

check it it's working fine please check all the css and jquery file is exist.
copy the below code and run it is working fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>QPZONE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">QPZONE</a>

        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">

        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">1st Year</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">2nd Year</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">3rd Year</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">4th Year</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>           
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you make any changes to the code?  With simply re-copying the question code, it's not evident that you're actually offering a solution.

Comment: thank you so much. Actually I just sorted out the mistake, which was with the script part.

Comment: An explanation of your code will be great, it's not enough to paste the full script.